# Changing multiple Numpy array elements using slicing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Say I have the `numpy` array `arr_1 = np.arange(10)` returning:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

How do I change *multiple* elements to a certain value using slicing?

For example: changing the zeroth, first and second element that occur every five elements, starting from the first element, to 100. I want this:

```
array([0, 100, 100, 100, 4, 5, 100, 100, 100, 9])
```

I tried `arr_1[1::[5, 6, 7]] = 100` but that doesn't work.

Comment: YOu are close -- just wrap your list of indexes in a numpy array constructor. See below for details.

Comment: Yes, slice arguments have to be numbers, not lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
a = np.arange(10)       # Input array
idx = np.array([0,1,2]) # Indices to be set
offset = 1              # Offset

a[np.in1d(np.mod(np.arange(a.size),5) , idx+offset)] = 100
```

Sample run with original sample -

```
In [849]: a = np.arange(10)       # Input array
     ...: idx = np.array([0,1,2]) # Indices to be set
     ...: offset = 1              # Offset
     ...: 
     ...: a[np.in1d(np.mod(np.arange(a.size),5) , idx+offset)] = 100
     ...: 

In [850]: a
Out[850]: array([  0, 100, 100, 100,   4,   5, 100, 100, 100,   9])
```

Sample run with `non-sequential indices` -

```
In [851]: a = np.arange(11)       # Input array
     ...: idx = np.array([0,2,3]) # Indices to be set
     ...: offset = 1              # Offset
     ...: 

In [852]: a[np.in1d(np.mod(np.arange(a.size),5) , idx+offset)] = 100

In [853]: a
Out[853]: array([  0, 100,   2, 100, 100,   5, 100,   7, 100, 100,  10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on what you did :

```
arr_1 = np.arange(10)
arr_1[1::5] = 100
arr_1[2::5] = 100
arr_1[3::5] = 100
```

and it returns :

```
array([  0, 100, 100, 100,   4,   5, 100, 100, 100,   9])
```

Comment: Or in loop form `for i in range(3): arr_1[i::5] = 100`.  If the number of loops is sufficiently smaller than the length of `arr_1` this should be faster than the 'fancier' solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If your repeat offset divides the array length:

```
a.reshape((-1, 5))[:, 1:4] = 100
```

General case requires two lines:

```
a[: len(a) // 5 * 5].reshape((-1, 5))[:, 1:4] = 100
a[len(a) // 5 * 5 :][1:4] = 100
```

How it works: Reshaping in the described way stacks consecutive stretches of the array in such a way that the target substretches are aligned and can therefore be addressed in one go using standard 2d indexing:

```
>>> a = np.arange(15)
>>> a.reshape((-1, 5))
array([[ 0,  1x,  2x,  3x,  4],
       [ 5,  6x,  7x,  8x,  9],
       [10, 11x, 12x, 13x, 14]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your list of indexes in np.array(list). You were very close to being correct:

```
In [2]: arr_1 = np.arange(10)

In [3]: arr_1[np.array([0,1,2,5,6,7])] = 100

In [4]: arr_1
Out[4]: array([100, 100, 100,   3,   4, 100, 100, 100,   8,   9])
```

I used hand coded values for the indexes, per your requirements.  You can get the indexes in an automated way using some technique you like, like that shown by Divakar.