# Periodically slice an list/array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have a `a = range(1,51)`. How can i slice `a` to create a new list that look like this:

```
[1,2,3,11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33,41,42,43]
```

Is there a pythonic way that can help me do this without writing function?

I know that `[start:stop:step`] for periodically slicing one element but i'm not sure if i'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: The suggested duplicate question/answer is not the same as mine question. I simply asked to slice/extract periodically elements from a larger list/array. The suggested duplicate modifies elements of existing array.

Comment: You need to use list comprehension

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. That was a brain fa#t.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing multiple Numpy array elements using slicing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092657/changing-multiple-numpy-array-elements-using-slicing-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/42092657/7207392 (same thing only operand is array not list, but then this here has `numpy` tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option you can go with *logical vector subsetting*, something like:

```
a[(a - 1) % 10 < 3]
# array([ 1,  2,  3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43])
```

---

`(a - 1) % 10` finds the remainder of array by 10 (period); and `(a - 1) % 10 < 3` gives a logical vector which gives true for the first three elements of every ten elements.

Comment: One thing to note is this only works for numpy.array. python list type doesn't work with this.

Comment: @AlexFung correct. OP has the `numpy` tagged, so I assume it is numpy array here.

Comment: Noted. But is brilliant and elegant ... Why did i not think of it? :0 :( :)

Comment: `If numpy==True: choose(this_answer)`  score+=1

Answer (score 2):

What you want is more complicated than a simple slice, so you're going to need some kind of (likely fairly simple) function to do it.  I'd look at using `zip` to combine multiple slices, something like:

`reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, map(list, zip(a[1::10], a[2::10], a[3::10])))`

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
>>> li=range(1,52)
```

You can do:

```
>>> [l for sl in [li[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(li),10)] for l in sl]
[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43, 51]
```

Or, if you want only full sublists:

```
>>> [l for sl in [li[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(li),10)] for l in sl if len(sl)==3]
[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43]
```

Or, given:

```
>>> li=range(1,51)
```

Then you do not need to test sublists:

```
>>> [l for sl in [li[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(li),10)] for l in sl]
[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43]
```

Answer (score 1):

Psidom's answer's index math can be adapted to a list comprehension too

```
a = range(1,51)

[n for n in a if (n - 1) % 10 < 3]

Out[23]: [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43]
```